# Boolean expressions in SQL Server jobs

Tags: sql-server, database

I have inherited a SQL Server "job" that does several things. There are two "steps" and each has multiple statements one is:

```
UPDATE Person
SET Person.LastName = P.LastName,
    Person.FirstName = P.FirstName,
    Person.MiddleName = P.MiddleName,
    Person.EmailAddress = P.EmailAddress,
    Person.StartDate = P.StartDate,
    Person.EndDate = P.EndDate
FROM OtherDB.dbo.Person Person
INNER JOIN FirstDB.dbo.Persons AS P ON P.PersonId = Person.PersonId
WHERE Person.LastName != P.LastName
   OR Person.FirstName != P.FirstName
   OR Person.MiddleName != P.MiddleName
   OR Person.EmailAddress != P.EmailAddress
   OR Person.StartDate != P.StartDate
   OR Person.EndDate != P.EndDate;
```

It is updating "person" data from FirstDB into OtherDB.  The `PersonId` columns  are `bigints` and are not null. The various "date" columns are of type `datetime` and could be NULL. The other columns are all `varchar` and could be NULL.

What I have learned is that, in the `where` clause, if NULL appears on either or both sides of the boolean operator the result is undefined.  Basically, NULL can neither equal nor not-equal NULL. It appears that the same applies to NULL and any other non-null value.

So I thought to try:

```
UPDATE Person
SET Person.LastName = P.LastName,
    Person.FirstName = P.FirstName,
    Person.MiddleName = P.MiddleName,
    Person.EmailAddress = P.EmailAddress,
    Person.StartDate = P.StartDate,
    Person.EndDate = P.EndDate
FROM OtherDB.dbo.Person Person
INNER JOIN FirstDB.dbo.Persons AS P ON P.PersonId = Person.PersonId
WHERE ISNULL(Person.LastName, '') != ISNULL(P.LastName, '')
   OR ISNULL(Person.FirstName, '') != ISNULL(P.FirstName, '')
   OR ISNULL(Person.MiddleName, '') != ISNULL(P.MiddleName, '')
   OR ISNULL(Person.EmailAddress, '') != ISNULL(P.EmailAddress, '')
   OR ISNULL(Person.StartDate, '') != ISNULL(P.StartDate, '')
   OR ISNULL(Person.EndDate, '') != ISNULL(P.EndDate, '');
```

This works in a regular query window but fails in the job.  The error is:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4145).  The step failed.

I am not seeing a problem. What am I missing?

**Edit**

As requested, for others in this situation: I edited this job by using SQL Server Management Studio.  I opened a connection to my target DB then opened the "SQL Server Agent" drop-down under the connection. I opened "Jobs" and found the job i was looking for.  I right-clicked on the job name and selected "Script Job As" -> "Drop and Create to" -> "New Query Window".  From there I copied the relevant sections to new query windows where I modified and tested them as necessary.  I then just copied and pasted the working sections back into the job window above -- COMPLETELY forgetting to double up the single quotes where necessary.

Comment: How did you add the step to the job? I wonder if a script you used escaped all of your double apostrophes and it is now trying to evaluate WHERE ISNULL(Person.LastName, **') != ISNULL(P.LastName, '**) - the bolded portion is a simple string literal, not an empty string and a comparison to another expression.

Comment: That was absolutely the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Be happy to add details about how you added the job/step so that others may be wary of the same approach. Did you generate dynamic SQL to add the job step, pass the T-SQL to Powershell, ...?

Answer (score 2):

How did you add the step to the job? I wonder if a script you used escaped all of your double apostrophes and it is now trying to evaluate

```
WHERE ISNULL(Person.LastName, ') != ISNULL(P.LastName, ')
------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's "valid enough" syntax. The highlighted portion is a simple string literal, not an empty string and a comparison to another expression.

Comment: As Aaron suggested, I just did a copy&past from a Drop&Create query window to other query windows where i edited and tested.  Then, I just C7P's the edited versions back into the job and forgetting to quote the single quotes.